# Queries in a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need some help please :)

I have

```
 ACCOUNTS
- account_id
- username
- password

USER_RIGHTS
- rights_id
- description
- level
```

There is many to many relationship (so I need a third table)
The `USER_RIGHTS` contains these valuse:

```
1,'READ_ACCOUNTS',0
2,'CREATE_ACCOUNTS',1
3,'UPDATE_ACCOUNTS',2
4,'DELETE_ACCOUNTS',3
5,'READ_ORDERS',0
6,'CREATE_ORDERS',1
7,'UPDATE_ORDERS',2
8,'DELETE_ORDERS',3
```

I need:
- a query that returns all accounts that do not have the right to delete anything
- a query that returns all accounts that have the maximum number of user rights

Thank you!

Comment: Well, this is no "we do your work for you" site. Show what you've tried and where the problem is.

Comment: select a.username  from ACCOUNTS a
left outer join ACCOUNTS_RIGHTS ar on a.account_id = ar.account_id
left outer join USER_RIGHTS ur on ar.rights_id = ur.rights_id
where ur.rights_id not in (4,8) 
group by a.username

this is for the first query - but for example in ACCOUNTS_RIGHTS if i have user 1 - right 1 and user 1 - right 4 it would return it and i don't want that :|

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE accounts_2_user_rights
(
  id int
  account_id int
  rights_id int  
)

-- all without delete right
select *
from accounts acc
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from rights_user ru
  inner join accounts_2_user_rights a2ur
    on a2ur.rights_id = ru.rights_id
    and a2ur.account_id = acc.account_id
  where ru.description like 'DELETE%'
)

-- all maximum
select account_id, count(1)
from accounts acc
where exists(
  select 1
  from accounts_2_user_rights a2ur  
  inner join user_rights ur
    on ur.rights_id = a2ur.rights_id
  where a2ur.account_id = acc.account_id
  and count(1) = 9
)
```

Comment: thank you for the first one, but all maximum is not ok, it says invalid use of an aggregate function

Comment: Ok, i didn't actually test it, its kind of pseudo code. You can skip the exists and just use a subquery in the where.. Something like (...) where (SELECT COUNT(1) (...)) = 9. Or use a GROUP BY and use the HAVING keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a example on SQLfiddle. By now I ill just tell what to do. I'll provide code if you provide code.

Basicaly you ill do a subquery over the user_rights join rights to get the accounts ids and feed a query over accounts.
this is the pseud code:

```
select * from accounts where account_id in (
    select account_id from user_rights_per_account
    join user_rights on user_right_id = user_right_id
    where (your filter)
)
```

You can do without subqueries but this way you don't need to use distinct.
You can do another subquery if you need to do a aggregate.